# How to snap a float to grid

Tags: spacing, floats, formatting, two-column

I have a two-column document with some column-spanning floats. The problem is that floats essentially reduce the page size when present, and the remaining page size does not necessarily correspond to an integral number of lines. Thus, TeX tries to align the text with the page boundaries by increasing the space between paragraphs.

A better solution would be to increase the space between the float and the text, which is done automatically for single-column documents. Is there any way to acheive this for two-column documents as well?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure*}
\kant[1-7]
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Desired solution:**
[image]

Comment: well.... you could `\topskip=10pt plus 12pt` at the start of your document  but I'm not sure I really want to suggest that, need to think about the consequences.

Comment: Is there any practical way to apply the suggested `topskip` flexibility only to pages containing a float..?

Comment: possibly.  I'll think about it. topskip may not be the best hook, certainly flexible topskip would be weird if you didn't just have plain text as the top baseline would move around. But shows that something must be possible...

Comment: I accepted John Kormylo's solution since it answers the question exactly. But I'm still interested in the `topskip` hook, since it's applicable to more complicated situations as well. Is it possible to place a modified `thispagestyle` in the float perhaps?

Comment: no pagestyle happens at a different time, in the output routine after the columns are made up as latex is adding the page head and foot. \topskip is a tex primitive that happens in the core of tex in the page breaker when white space is discarded at the break and replaced  by \topskip-height of first line, more or less.

Comment: \advance\topskip by 0pt plus 0.01fil also works, except on the last page (or any other page using glue).

Comment: Dooh!  \parskip=\lineskip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of principle.  The idea is to reduce the remaining space on the page to a multiple of `\baselineskip`.

Note that `\baselineskip` could change between the figure creation and final location (not likely unless you like to change font sizes).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mwe}

% skip to the next grid interval
\newcommand{\vgrid}[2]% #1 = remaining page, #2 =  grid interval (\e.g. \baselineskip)
{\bgroup% use local registers
  \dimen0=#1\relax
  \dimen1=#2\relax
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen0 / \dimen1\relax
  \advance \dimen0 by -\count1\dimen1
  \ifdim\dimen0<0pt \advance\dimen0 by \dimen1\fi
  \vskip\dimen0
\egroup}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{figureboxstar}[1][t]{\@dblfloat{figure}[#1]
  \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \BODY
  \end{minipage}}%
  \usebox0\vgrid{\dimexpr\textheight-\topskip-\ht0-\dp0-\dbltextfloatsep}{\baselineskip}%
\end@dblfloat}

\NewEnviron{figurebox}[1][t]{\@float{figure}[#1]
 \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \BODY
  \end{minipage}}%
  \usebox0\vgrid{\dimexpr\textheight-\topskip-\ht0-\dp0-\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}%
\end@float}

\renewenvironment{figure}{\figurebox}{\endfigurebox}
\renewenvironment{figure*}{\figureboxstar}{\endfigureboxstar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=10cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

It turned out that replacing the `figure` and `figure*` environments was easier then expected.  (I started out trying to use `\@ifstar`.)

Comment: Wow. I don't claim to understand every part of the macro, but it seems to work! As far as I understand, you save the figure in a box first, then measure the height. You feed the result to the function `\gap` which calculates the required extra spacing. Finally, you place the box and add the extra space. But I would _never_ have figured out this stuff myself... Thought I knew how to code, but that was before I started to write LaTeX macros..

Comment: BTW what is the best way of redefining the figure environment so that this solution is used for every float?

Comment: BTW, it occurred to me that \textheight may not be an even multiple of \baselineskip.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for the edit :-) I tried to redefine the environments myself, but got lost because of the star thing... I would give you another upvote if I could!

Comment: ..it should be `\dbltextfloatsep` in the `figureboxstar` environment, right? Tried to edit it myself, but apparently the edit was too small to be approved :-)