# Keep text at consistent height in IEEEtran

Tags: vertical-alignment, ieeetran

When compiling the following code in latex:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

The following output is generated:
[image]

The columns are not aligned with each other but this is a requirement for the conference I need to submit to.
Does latex have a way to automatically fix this or is it necessary to add manual \vspace{} after every figure?

Comment: Note that `\lipsum[1-8]` does not quite fill the page.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292230/how-to-snap-a-float-to-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a conference requirement, they should fix `\textfloatsep` to handle it.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\advance\textfloatsep by \fill

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```